# MS Excel 2007 Custom Format

Tags: excel-2007

I would like to make a column uniformed by adding a "~" if the number in the field is not ten digits. For example: 123456789~,  2343456~~~, and 543645~~~~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is in cell A1.  The following formula should work.  This is not VBA code.  Just put it in another cell.

```
=A1 & REPT("~", 10-LEN(A1))
```

Comment: clever. I miss-read the question and was trying to do that with the formatting options ... to no avail +1 -- The title and the text are not coincident.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that formula to work. I will repost with a better title.